# Правильное именование проектов Django

Tags: django

Подскажите, как вы именуете папки Django проекта при создании? Допустим я начинаю новый проект `new_project`. Для начала хочется создать для проекта папку, поднять там виртуальное окружение и поставить все нужное:

```
.
└── new_project
    └── venv
```

Далее я стартую Django проект, структура следующая:

```
.
└── new_project
    ├── new_project
    │   ├── manage.py
    │   └── new_project
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── settings.py
    │       ├── urls.py
    │       └── wsgi.py
    └── venv
        ├── bin
        │   ├── ...
```

И вот эта структура из трех вложенных new_project'ов меня смущает. Может быть есть способ избежать подобного

Comment: Самый верхний new_project выкинуть, venv положить внутрь друого new_project рядом с manage.py и будет нормально

Answer (score 2):

Избавиться от одной вложенности поможет точка в конце команды `django-admin startproject project .`

В итоге получится примерно так

```
.
├── new_project
│   ├── manage.py
│   └── project
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── settings.py
│       ├── urls.py
│       └── wsgi.py
└── venv
    ├── bin
    │   ├── ...
```